# Can't scroll modal pop-up on Safari

Tags: ios, iphone

We have this product as example https://www.iris-boutique.ro/home/372-set-alessandra-blue-cu-aur-alb-si-diamante-cz.html

Here if we enter by iphone and click on "Vezi poze 360", it will show 3 photos that ar 360 mode. The problem is that i can't scroll down to see all photos.

I dont' know if it's something from the popup or the photo's script.

It's only not working on iOS. On Android it's all good.

Maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Your modal VC needs an embedded UIScrollView

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks.